# Error message 'InterfaceName' does not implement interface member 'InterfaceMember'

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

The code below gives me this error:

> 'JsonWcfService.GetVenues' does not implement interface member
> 'GetVenuesByLocation(string search)'.

I am fairly new to C# and .NET so most of this is copy and paste.

**IGetVenues.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
 
namespace JsonWcfService
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IGetVenues
    {
        [OperationContract]
        //attribute for returning JSON format
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
            UriTemplate = "json/Venues/search={search}")]
        //method
        List<Venue> GetAllVenuesMethod(string search);
 
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
            UriTemplate = "json/Venues/location={search}")]
        List<Venueloc> GetVenuesByLocation(string search); 
    }
}
```

**GetVenues.svc.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
namespace JsonWcfService
{
    public class GetVenues : IGetVenues 
    {
        public List<Venue> GetAllVenuesMethod(string search)
        {
            List<Venue> mylist = new List<Venue>();
 
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("server=*****;database=******;Trusted_Connection=True;"))
            {
                conn.Open();
                string cmdStr = String.Format("Select id,name,address1,town,postcode,lon,lat from venuesearch WHERE searchterm like @searchterm");
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdStr, conn);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("searchterm", "%" + Convert.ToString(search) + "%"));
                SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (rd.HasRows)
                {
                    while (rd.Read())
                        mylist.Add(new Venue(
                            rd.GetInt32(0),
                            //rd.GetString(1),
                            rd.IsDBNull(1) ? null : rd.GetString(1),
                            //rd.GetString(2), 
                            rd.IsDBNull(2) ? null : rd.GetString(2),
                            //rd.GetString(3),
                            rd.IsDBNull(3) ? null : rd.GetString(3),
                            //rd.GetString(4)
                            rd.IsDBNull(4) ? null : rd.GetString(4),
                            //rd.GetString(4)
                            rd.IsDBNull(5) ? 0 : rd.GetDecimal(5),
                            //rd.GetString(4)
                            rd.IsDBNull(6) ? 0 : rd.GetDecimal(6)
                            ));
                }
                conn.Close();
            }
 
            return mylist;
        }
    }
 
    [DataContract]
 
    public class Venue
    {
        [DataMember]
        public Int32 id { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string name { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string address1 { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string town { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string postcode { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public Decimal lon { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public Decimal lat { get; set; }
        public Venue(int venid, string venname, string venaddress1, string ventown, string venpostcode, decimal venlon, decimal venlat)
        {
            id = venid;
            name = venname;
            address1 = venaddress1;
            town = ventown;
            postcode = venpostcode;
            lon = venlon;
            lat = venlat;
 
        }
 
        public List<Venueloc> GetVenuesByLocation(string search)
        {
            List<Venueloc> mylist = new List<Venueloc>();
 
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("server=***;database=******;Trusted_Connection=True;"))
            {
                conn.Open();
                string cmdStr = String.Format("Select id,name,address1,town,postcode,lon,lat from venuesearch WHERE searchterm like @searchterm");
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdStr, conn);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("searchterm", "%" + Convert.ToString(search) + "%"));
                SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (rd.HasRows)
                {
                    while (rd.Read())
                        mylist.Add(new Venueloc(
                            rd.GetInt32(0),
                            //rd.GetString(1),
                            rd.IsDBNull(1) ? null : rd.GetString(1),
                            //rd.GetString(2), 
                            rd.IsDBNull(2) ? null : rd.GetString(2),
                            //rd.GetString(3),
                            rd.IsDBNull(3) ? null : rd.GetString(3),
                            //rd.GetString(4)
                            rd.IsDBNull(4) ? null : rd.GetString(4),
                            //rd.GetString(4)
                            rd.IsDBNull(5) ? 0 : rd.GetDecimal(5),
                            //rd.GetString(4)
                            rd.IsDBNull(6) ? 0 : rd.GetDecimal(6)
                            ));
                }
                conn.Close();
            }
 
            return mylist;
        }
    }
 
    [DataContract]
 
    public class Venueloc
    {
        [DataMember]
        public Int32 id { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string name { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string address1 { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string town { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string postcode { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public Decimal lon { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public Decimal lat { get; set; }
        public Venueloc(int venid, string venname, string venaddress1, string ventown, string venpostcode, decimal venlon, decimal venlat)
        {
            id = venid;
            name = venname;
            address1 = venaddress1;
            town = ventown;
            postcode = venpostcode;
            lon = venlon;
            lat = venlat;
 
        }
    }
}
```

The first function works but the second one doesn't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your class `GetVenues` does not implement the method mentioned in your error message. Where exactly are you stuck? `GetVenuesByLocation(string search)` is defined in the class `Venue`.

I have noticed that this question is starting to garner interest. The issue here is very easy: your class does not implement (even if it's `abstract`, you have to define them) all methods defined in the interface. Your IDE should warn you of this before compiling.

Comment: Where do i need to put it to not get the error if i move it down i get even more errors.

Comment: You have to move that method to the class `GetVenues`. Horrible class name by the way.

Comment: Thank you ! with your help i managed to get my head round it!

Comment: Have to agree with Jeroen, in this situation you would normally have a IVenueService , impelemnted by VenueService, which contains a Methode GetAllVenues, a class is a grouping of similar data and functions , get and set imply action so should only be used tor naming functions that perform the action, in this case your single function does the getting and your class is a group of functions and data (all be it a group which currently only contains 2 functions and no data) relating to making a service for venues

Answer (score 2):

Second function is inside the class Venue not in GetVenues, move it to GetVenues