# Does not implement interface member StartActivityInAndroid

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am trying to open an activity in MainPage through dependency and have the following error:

[image]

[image]

Can you help me? Thanks

Comment: The error message is fairly self-explanatory. You are implementing an interface, which by definition is a contract. The contract states that you must have a method called `StartActivityInAndroid` that returns nothing and takes no parameters. Perhaps you need to read up on interfaces in general: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/

Comment: please do NOT post code or errors as images!

Comment: @howcheng 
And I already have this method in the interface ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [does not implement interface member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18291051/does-not-implement-interface-member)

Comment: Yes, but you don't have this method in the class, which is what VS is telling you.

Comment: It looks like you have a typo in your `NativePages` class.  Where you have `public void StartAc()` it should be `public void StartActivityInAndroid()`.  Correct that and your error will go away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A C# interface is basically a contract - if your class implements an interface, you are saying that you will do all the things the interface requires.

In this case, your class is implementing `INativePages` which defines a method `StartActivityAndroid`.  So your class **must** provide an implementation of that method signature.

If you click on the "show potential fixes" link VS will automatically create a method stub for you.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take an example. Say that I am a Robot and I can shoot people all around around me. But, the issue is I don't have a gun. I also don't understand how a gun works. But I know that a gun is an object which has a trigger which when pressed kills people. So, the code for this will look something like below:-

```
public class Robot{

    public void ShootPeopleWith( weapon IWeapon ){
        weapon.PressTrigger()
    }
}

interface IWeapon{
   PressTrigger()
}
```

You see the Robot expects anyone who wants it to shoot people to provide him with a weapon first. Now, he doesn't know what weapon. Whatever you provide me, it should have a trigger because I only know to press the trigger and I know it serves my purpose. If you provide me with something that doesn't have a trigger, I cannot function.

Now, there comes a drone that instructs the Robot to shoot people. It also provides it with a gun.

```
public class Drone{
    List<Robots> allRobotsInArea = someList

    public void DelegateARobot(){
        robot = select a robot from allRobotsInArea
        IWeapon weapon = new MachineGun();    //procuring a machine gun
        robot.ShootPeopleWith(weapon);
    }

}
```

You can see here that IWeapon is an agreement between the Robot and Drone. It says that whatever you give me must have a trigger. So, machine gun must have a trigger. Let's implement few weapons:-

```
public class MachineGun : IWeapon{
    public void PressTrigger(){
        Fire40RoundsPerSecond();
    }
    ...
}

public class Sniper() : IWeapon{
    public void PressTrigger(){
        SayQuackQauck();
    }
}
```

The Drone can now easily pass in any weapon like Sniper and MachineGun to the Robot.

```
public class Pumpkin{
    public void FreakPeopleOut(){
        GlowInTheDark();
    }
}
```

The drone cannot pass in a Pumpkin even though it can be used as a weapon as `robot.ShootPeopleWith(new Pumpkin());` because it doesn't have a trigger and breaches the contract that Robot expects.

In your case, the Android Operating System is possibly the Robot in the above story which expects anything of type INativePages so when it consumes your NativePages object, it will try to call StartActivityInAndroid(). It doesn't know the activity or how to start it, so you must specify it in the method. Pressing Alt + Enter in Windows will auto-generate this method for you. You will have to then write logic on how to Start the Activity in Android.